# Profile Swift Package

Tags: swift, xcode, profiler, swift-package-manager

The "profile" option under menu Product > Profile (cmd + i) is greyed out for Swift Package in Xcode. I would like to know where in my code I have performance bottlenecks.

How can I profile my Swift Package? Is it possible **without creating an Xcode proj**? Maybe through CLI somehow?

I really love coding Swift without the old and messy Xcode project file, but maybe this is a scenario where it is needed?

Comment: Not sure about the profiling part of packages, but even if they don't support it, you don't have to stop using SPM, you can just generate an Xcode project from your package for the profiling, then delete the project once you're done with the profiling and renegerate it again when you need it again - assuming you only want to profile sporadically.

Comment: Ofc I can do that, and is a reasonable fallback, but I'd rather not if there is a CLI command for it, but I haven't found any (yet?).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the main things that "Product -> Profile" does by default is to create a release build, and launch Instruments.app. You can do both of those things yourself, manually.

You can create a release build  like this:

```
swift build -c release
```

This creates an executable located at YourProjectRoot/.build/release/executableName.

Then you can launch instruments from Xcode by doing "Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Instruments" in the menu bar.

Choose an instruments template, and select your executable as the target to profile using

[image]

In the same dialog, you can set environment variables, command line arguments, and the working directory for your executable. You only need to do this once, as the next time you open Instruments, it would remember the target you selected.

Then you can start profiling.

Comment: ```"Product -> Profile" does is to create a release build, and launch Instruments.app```
Will it be a release build or it depends on the scheme?

Comment: @TejuAmirthi You're right, it depends on the scheme, and by default it is set to use the release configuration when profiling. I tried to not overcomplicate it too much. Maybe I've left out too much? And is there a situation where you would want to profile a debug build anyway?

Comment: I guess you answered just enough for the question. I never actually gave a thought to why profile specific debug/release build till now. Will it help in profiling release build and not debug build? Any debug method call trace being present, will it help?